# Data structures - O(1) complexity

Tags: data-structures, hash, avl-tree

So I've been given the next question:
Describe a data structure by the following interface:

- The structure will contain n elements, where each element holds a key and a value (meaning, each element is (key, value)).
- insert ((key, value)): insert an element in O(1) average case and O(log n) worst case.
- delete ((key, value)): delete the element that correspond to the given key in O(1) average case and O(log n) worst case.
- find (key): find the element that correspond to the given key and return it's value in O(1) average case and O(log n) worst case.
- setAll (m): change the value of each element in the structure to be m in O(1) **worst case**

So my main thought was to use a hash table to ensure O(1) average case runtime for insert, delete, find. the hash table will be implmented by chaining, but instead of linked list, use an AVL tree, so in the worst case, insert, delete and find will be O(log n).
But I got stuck on setAll. I can't deal with this problem in O(1) worst case runtime. I know that you can't really change all the values because it requires traversal on the elements, so I thought maybe I can use global variables and keep track of the calls for setAll but I can't really see how I implement such thing.
In addition, there is no limit on the space complxity, which is why I used a hash table containing AVL trees. This is also a clue that our lecturer gave us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A hash table with AVL trees is a good start.

To implement `setAll(m)`, keep an operation counter, and mark each entry with `update_op = operation_count` during `insert`.

When `setAll(m)` is called, set a field `last_reset = operation_count` and `reset_value = m`.

Then modify `find` so it returns `reset_value` for any entry with `update_op < last_reset`.

Comment: Thank you! sounds good actually, this was just the missing piece in the puzzle